# EWS fails with 'read ECONNRESET' on Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, ews-javascript-api

Using these libraries to connect to ews and get emails:

- "ews-javascript-api": "^0.10.3"
- "ews-javascript-api-auth": "^1.2.1"

Locally it works and I can connect to email boxes but when I run it on Jenkins I get this error:

```
SoapFaultDetails {
  message: 'read ECONNRESET',
  InnerException: null,
  faultCode: null,
  faultString: null,
  faultActor: null,
  responseCode: 127,
  errorCode: 0,
  exceptionType: null,
  lineNumber: 0,
  positionWithinLine: 0,
  errorDetails: DictionaryWithStringKey {
    keys: [],
    keysToObjs: {},
    objects: {},
    keyPicker: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  HttpStatusCode: undefined
}
```

A function which connects and read the email:

```js
function getEws(user, password, host, subject) {

  ews.ConfigurationApi.ConfigureXHR(new ewsAuth.ntlmAuthXhrApi(user, password))
  const service = new ews.ExchangeService(ews.ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1)
  service.Credentials = new ews.WebCredentials(user, password)
  service.Url = new ews.Uri(host)

  service
    .SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(
      [new ews.FolderId(ews.WellKnownFolderName.Inbox)],
      ews.EventType.NewMail,
      ews.EventType.Created,
      ews.EventType.Deleted,
      ews.EventType.Modified,
      ews.EventType.Moved,
      ews.EventType.Copied,
      ews.EventType.FreeBusyChanged
    )
    .then(function (streamingSubscription) {
      var connection = new ews.StreamingSubscriptionConnection(service, 1)
      connection.AddSubscription(streamingSubscription)
      connection.OnNotificationEvent.push(function (obj) {
        ews.EwsLogging.Log(obj, true, true)
        const searchFilter = new ews.SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(ews.LogicalOperator.And, [
          new ews.SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ews.ItemSchema.Subject, subject)
        ])

        const itemview = new ews.ItemView(1)

        const foundItems = service.FindItems(ews.WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, itemview)

        const adinationalProps = []
        adinationalProps.push(ews.ItemSchema.TextBody)

        foundItems.then(function (response) {
          for (const item of response.Items) {
            item
              .Load(new ews.PropertySet(ews.BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, adinationalProps))
              .then(function () {
                fs.writeFileSync('cypress/fixtures/email.txt', item.TextBody.text)
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(' ----- Load error start ----- ')
                console.error(error)
                console.log(' ----- Load error end ----- ')
              })
          }
        })
      })
      connection.OnDisconnect.push(function (connection, subscriptionErrorEventArgsInstance) {
        ews.EwsLogging.Log(subscriptionErrorEventArgsInstance, true, true)
      })
      connection.Open()
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(' ----- SubscribeToStreamingNotifications error start ----- ')
      console.error(error)
      console.log(' ----- SubscribeToStreamingNotifications error end ----- ')
    })
}
```

I would be grateful for any ideas on how to solve this issue on Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was an issue with expired SSL certificates on Travis's side.